# Cannot resolve method requestLocationUpdates

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I'm trying to call method requestLocationUpdates, but eventually i get an error message "cannot resolve method ".
I think it's because of "this" argument, but i'm not sure.
I imported LocationListener, but it didn't help me.

Here is my part of code:

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainMap extends ActionBarActivity implements LocationListener {

    private void addMarker(){
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());
        if(status!= ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ // Google Play Services are not available

            int requestCode = 10;
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
            dialog.show();

        }else { // Google Play Services are available
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

            if (location != null) {
                onLocationChanged(location);
            }

            // troubles here
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 10, this);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(20));
    }

}
```

Comment: What version of the Android SDK are you targeting your app to?

Comment: I think it's ok with sdk version. Now i have minSdkVersion 11, targetSdkVersion 21.

Answer (score 8):

You are importing `LocationListener` from the wrong package. You seem to be importing it as:

```
com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener
```

but the `requestLocationUpdates (String provider, long minTime, float minDistance, LocationListener listener)` method the last argument of this type:

```
android.location.LocationListener
```

as you can see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener)).

Changing the import statements to load `android.location.LocationListener` should fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You should implement `LocationListener` for MainActivityClass and also overwrite implement methods: `onLocationChanged`, `onStatusChanged`, `onProviderEnabled`, `onProviderDisabled`.

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
             implements OnMapReadyCallback, LocationListener
```

I got same Error and its fixed by implementing as mentioned above.

Comment: Hi Ganesh, welcome to StackOverlow. Try to better formatting your responses. You can use edit and the tools "{ }" in the upper bar to nicely format code snippets like this